# Does Fedora get security patches faster than CentOS?

Tags: centos, fedora, rhel, security

CentOS is a community based, downstream source rebuild of RedHat Enterpise Linux (RHEL). The [CentOS website states](https://wiki.centos.org/FAQ/General#How_long_after_Red_Hat_publishes_a_fix_does_it_take_for_CentOS_to_publish_a_fix.3F) that security patches from RHEL take 24-72 hours to land in CentOS.

Fedora is the upstream distro for RHEL, as releases of RHEL are forked from Fedora.  This would suggest that patches are made to Fedora before making it to RHEL, but RHEL isn't exactly a downstream repo from Fedora:

1. Red Hat [removes and modifies a lot of software](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/quick-docs/fedora-and-red-hat-enterprise-linux/index.html) from the Fedora release before it becomes a RHEL release.
2. RHEL releases backport fixes for 10 years whereas, Fedora releases are [EoL after 13 months](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Fedora_Release_Life_Cycle).
3. RHEL [obfuscates patches to frustrate clones](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2011/03/04/red_hat_twarts_oracle_and_novell_with_change_to_source_code_packaging/) like Oracle and SUSE.

Do security patches hit Fedora before RHEL?  If not, is there any easy answer to how long fixes from RHEL take to get to Fedora vs CentOS?  I'll take an incomplete rough estimate too :)

Comment: Is there anything more recent than 2011 to support (3)?

Answer (score 6):

It’s a bit more complicated than that. While it is true that Red Hat forks from Fedora, each RHEL release is maintained entirely separately from Fedora from that point on.

And since people are paying for [RHEL security updates](https://access.redhat.com/security/updates/backporting), you’ll see them sooner in RHEL than Fedora, depending on severity. Security updates, bug fixes and feature updates will appear in Fedora depending on how quick the Fedora packager releases it.

As for CentOS, it relies on the change appearing in RHEL first. Once Red Hat sends the new package source to CentOS, it will be built soonish (depending on the build cycle. For example, all the updates to 8.2 are queued up until the CentOS release for 8.2 is finished).

Comment: So does Red Hat deliberately withhold patches for RHEL that would apply to Fedora until after the source dump?  Do Fedora maintainers require the same 24-72 hour window to fix security errata from RHEL?

Comment: The people patching RHEL are most likely completely different people. The security fixes for RHEL might not even apply to Fedora packages. Usually the solution in Fedora is to wait for the upstream project to release a fix and deploy the new version, while Red Hat is an enterprise Linux distro so it backports security fixes to the version in RHEL.

Comment: @Indolering Not sure what you're suggesting, but note that most packages in a supported Fedora release are of a different (newer) version than the equivalents in supported RHEL releases, so direct code sharing is rarely possible. If an issue affects both RHEL and Fedora, a tracking bug will be created for either one and processed by the respective maintainers. Those might or might not be the same people, and if they are, it's IMHO fairly reasonable that the person first focuses on fixing the RHEL side for paying customers and only then switches to fix Fedora as well.

Answer (score 3):

> Does Fedora get **security** patches faster than CentOS

Subjective.

When it is a *decent* security patch my experience is that patch is simply released.  Which is especially true for **RHEL and CentOS** where CentOS follows RHEL in lockstep regarding version releases.

With RHEL/CentOS version 7.8 now being kernel 3.10, is quite different than Fedora whatever now which is kernel 4.x.  I say apples and oranges, so it really depends on the what the **security patch** is.  A **security** patch may only be applicable to Fedora kernel 4.x and not RHEL 3.x kernel so that may give the **impression** Fedora gets security patches sooner, which is not untrue.  Fedora is an *upstream* release to RHEL, meaning as Fedora moves along at a fast *development* pace it should be expected to simply see **more** security patches come out for Fedora over time as it moves at that faster pace, rather than the stable pace of RHEL/CentOS.  But that should not be interpreted Fedora gets more security patches [sooner] therefore is better.

A better question might be what degree of delay is there between *update* releases between RHEL and CentOS.  For example when RHEL updated from 7.6 to 7.7 for whatever 3.x kernel that was,  CentOS is always some number of weeks, or months, until CentOS follows in lockstep.  You can read those questions on the centos forum and the same reply by trevor of don't ask me it'll be out when it's out as the CentOS people strip the RHEL tradename out of the software and do whatever else they need to do to release **free** Centos 7.7.

Comment: Your comment about kernel versions is correct, but not for the reason you think. RHEL locks the kernel version string on release, and backports large numbers of things from the current mainline (both bug fixes, and new features). So even back when Fedora was on 3.10 (about 5 years ago), the kernels would have been quite different, as Fedora was using the upstream kernel.org release, while RHEL was using their custom patched version.